# Intents Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, android-intent

Estoy desarrollando una app, que el primer activity tiene un TextView que muestra el mensaje "Usa el botón + para crear un nuevo usuario". Una vez que se pulsa dicho botón, va a una segunda actividad que captura nombre e email y lo envía de vuelta a la primera actividad, para elaborar un string a ser mostrado en el mismo TextView del mensaje inicial.
El problema que se presenta es que cuando cierro el app y lo abro otra vez, no me muestra "Usa el botón + para crear un nuevo usuario", sino "null", como si estuviese llegando un intent de la otra actividad. Cabe destacar que solo muestra ese mensaje solo inmediatamente después de la instalación del app. Adjunto código.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private User user;
TextView tv1;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    tv1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv1);
    tv1.setText("Usa el botón + "+
            "\n para crear un nuevo usuario");

    Intent callingIntent = getIntent();
    Bundle extras = callingIntent.getExtras();
    Toast.makeText(this, callingIntent.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    if(extras==null){//para para colocar mensaje "Usa el botón para crear un nuevo usuario, si no ha venido nada de la otra actividad"
        tv1.setText("Usa el botón + "+
                "\n para crear un nuevo usuario");
    }else{
        String strValue = callingIntent.getStringExtra("DATONAME");
        String strValue1 = callingIntent.getStringExtra("DATOEMAIL");

        user = new User(strValue,strValue1);
        String user_name = user.getNombre();
        String user_email = user.getEmail();
        int user_id = user.getId();
        String data = "Id: "+user_id+"\n"+
                      "Usuario: "+user_name+"\n"+
                      "Email: "+user_email;
        tv1.setText(data);
        
    }




    FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
    //ClickShrinkEffectKt.applyClickShrink(fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Registrar Usuario", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
            irSegundaActivity(view);
        }
    });
}

private void irSegundaActivity(View view) {
    Intent i = new Intent(this,ActivityLogin.class);
    startActivity(i);
    finish();
}
```

}

De antemano muchas gracias a los distinguidos foristas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que lo estás planteando mal. En estos casos en vez de comprobar si se ha venido de una segunda activity o no, lo mejor es indicar que queremos lanzar la segunda activity para obtener algo, para esto se usa [StartActivityForResult](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result?hl=es-419).

Para ello necesitarás:

1. Declarar un código para saber qué resultado estás obteniendo **en tu actividad principal**: `public static final int REQUEST_CODE = 1;`
2. **Cuando lanzas la segunda actividad**, debes indicar que esperas obtener un resultado:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, activity2.class);
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
```

3. **En la segunda clase tras hacer la lógica que quieras,** debes indicar que se ha terminado la ejecución Y **adjuntar el dato que quieres devolver**:

```
Intent answerIntent = new Intent();//Nuevo intent EN BLANCO
answerIntent.putExtra("answerMsg", "Mensaje a devolver");//Adjuntamos el dato
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, answerIntent);//Usamos setResult para indicar que todo fue OK y pasamos el intent con el dato que queramos
finish();//Terminamos la activity actual
```

4. Finalmente, en la main activity puedes recoger los datos devueltos (Lo suyo habría sido usar un bundle en vez de poner el dato directamente en el intent, pero funciona exactamente igual):

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE) {//Comprobamos que el código es el que pusimos nosotros al lanzar la segunda activity
        if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){//Si el resultado es OK
            String message = intent.getStringExtra("answerMsg")));
            //Haz lo que quieras con el mensaje aquí
        }
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {//Si algo ha ido mal o se ha cancelado
            Toast.makeText(this, "Error al recuperar el mensaje.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

De esta manera, cuando inicias la aplicación no necesitas controlar si el usuario ha guardado dato alguno, porque siempre se iniciará en blanco y al volver a la activity no necesitarás comprobar nada, siempre se ejecutará el `onActivityResult`. Creo que esta es la manera más sencilla de usar otras Activity para devolver datos a la actual.

Comment: @ Benito-B si, lo mejor fué lanzar la segunda actividad para obtener algo. Utlilicé tu el código que colocaste como recomendación y si funcionó.

Comment: el siguiente es el código que utilicé con tu recomendación, que si funcionó. Mil gracias.

Comment: ok...revisaré tu repositorio de github...

Answer (score 0):

La recepcion de datos en una Activity se realiza cuando abres la Activity desde un Intent, pero en este caso MainActivity se carga al abrir la aplicaciòn, esta no va a recibir informaciòn:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    ...
    ...
    Intent callingIntent = getIntent();
    Bundle extras = callingIntent.getExtras();
    ...
    ...

}
```

La soluciòn es que uses una opciòn de almacenamiento de android para que cuando inicie la app obtengas los valores que previamente guardaste al cerrarla, por ejemplo preferencias o base de datos:

[**Android almacenamiento de archivos y datos**](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage?hl=es-419)

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
public static final int REQUEST_CODE = 1;
private User user;
TextView tv1;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    tv1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv1);
    tv1.setText("Usa el botón + "+
            "\n para crear un nuevo usuario");

      
    FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            irSegundaActivity(view);
            Snackbar.make(view, "Registrar Usuario", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();

        }
    });
}

private void irSegundaActivity(View view) {
    Intent i = new Intent(this,ActivityLogin.class);
    startActivityForResult(i,REQUEST_CODE);

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
            String strValue = data.getStringExtra("DATONAME");
            String strValue1 = data.getStringExtra("DATOEMAIL");
            //String strValue = extras.getString("DATONAME");
            //String strValue1 = extras.getString("DATOEMAIL");

            user = new User(strValue,strValue1);
            String user_name = user.getNombre();
            String user_email = user.getEmail();
            int user_id = user.getId();
            String datauser = "Id: "+user_id+"\n"+
                    "Usuario: "+user_name+"\n"+
                    "Email: "+user_email;
            tv1.setText(datauser);
        }
    }
}
```

}

```
public class ActivityLogin extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

EditText edt1;
EditText edt2;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    findViewById(R.id.button_registro).setOnClickListener(this);
    edt1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.username);
    edt2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.email);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    int viewClicked = view.getId();
    String name_string = edt1.getText().toString();
    String email_string = edt2.getText().toString();
    if(viewClicked == R.id.button_registro){
        Intent intent = new Intent();

        intent.putExtra("DATONAME", name_string);
        intent.putExtra("DATOEMAIL",email_string);
        setResult(RESULT_OK,intent);
        finish();//finaliza esta actividad

    }
}
```

}

El ejercicio ejecuta lo siguiente:
1.- La clase MainActivity contiene un FloatActionButton que llama al método irSegundaActivity(view), para ir a la ActivityLogin por medio de un Intent i y del método startActivityForResult(i,REQUEST_CODE).
2.- Una vez en ActivityLogin, se pide un nombre de usuario y un email. Una vez escritos estos, el evento onClick del botón "button_registro"  declara un Intent, a su vez dos extra para enviar el nombre y el email del usuario. Una vez hecho esto, se invoca a setResult(RESULT_OK,intent), para enviar estos extras a la actividad de origen, y posteriormente  se invoca a finish(), para finalizar ActividadLogin.
3.- Regresando otra vez a MainActivity, el método setResult de ActivityLogin envía la informacion almacenados en los extras a onActivityResult, que recibe tres parámetros: resquestCode, que es el código que identifica que la información fue solicitda desde esta actividad en startActivityForResult(i,REQUEST_CODE); el resultCode, que es el código de resultado enviado desde ActivityLogin en setResult(RESULT_OK,intent); y tercero, el intent. Luego, se recupera los datos de los extras y se declara un objeto de la clase User (una clase que contiene tres atributos: nombre, email y id, esta última generada aleatoriamente y que pasamos parámetros a través de su constructor). Posteriormente, se realiza una cadena de caracteres (datauser) con el id, nombre e email y la pasamos como parámetros al TextView tv1 por medio del método setText.

Comment: @BetaM si estoy respondiendo